# Microsoft Translate Text Stopped Working - PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I've been using this library to translate text using Microsoft cognitive translator.

[PHP Microsoft Translate package](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-PHP/blob/master/Translate.php)

I have an Azure account and I think my endpoints and keys are still valid.  I had not changed anything in the interim, although I have the "free" package.

The code I had actually translate multiple languages and worked fine before.  For some reason it STOPPED working in the recently.  I edited the post to set:

```
$host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com", thank you (typo).
```

It actually does work if I set $text to something simple like:

```
$text = 'Guten Morgen!  Mit Corona zusammenraufen.Milde gesagt: Es sind keine besonders beruhigenden Nachrichten.';
```

returns English:

```
{"text":"Good morning! To put it mildly, it's not particularly reassuring news.","to":"en"}
```

If I slightly lengthen the string to:

```
$text = 'Guten Morgen!  Mit Corona zusammenraufen.  Milde gesagt: Es sind keine besonders beruhigenden Nachrichten. Milde gesagt: Es sind keine besonders beruhigenden Nachrichten.';
```

I get a:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

This worked previously with much longer strings for input.  I have a "free" plan with Azure.  Is it possible that there is now a limit to string length with my Azure account ?

The code that I have is.  There is some extra stuff for putting the translations into a database.

```
$key = 'MicrosoftKEY';
$host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
$path = "/translate?api-version=3.0";
$languages = $data['languagearray'];  // array of languages to translate to.
$params = '&from=' . $data["from"] ;  // language to translate from
foreach ($languages as $language) {
$params .= "&to=" . $language;
}
$params .= "&textType=html";
$text = $data["text"];  // text to translate

if (!function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
  function com_create_guid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
  }
}
// function to return the translated text, seem below, $json = jsonp_decode($result, true)[0]["translations"];

function Translate ($host, $path, $key, $params, $content) {

    $headers = "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
        "Content-length: " . strlen($content) . "\r\n" .
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n" .
        "X-ClientTraceId: " . com_create_guid() . "\r\n";
    // NOTE: Use the key 'http' even if you are making an HTTPS request. See:
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
    $options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'header' => $headers,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $content
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create ($options);
    $result = file_get_contents ($host . $path . $params, false, $context);
    echo $result;
    return $result;
}
$requestBody = array (
    array (
        'Text' => $text,
    ),
);

function jsonp_decode($jsonp, $assoc = false) { // PHP 5.3 adds depth as third parameter to json_decode
    if($jsonp[0] !== '[' && $jsonp[0] !== '{') { // we have JSONP
       $jsonp = substr($jsonp, strpos($jsonp, '('));
    }
    return json_decode(trim($jsonp,'();'), $assoc);
}

$content = json_encode($requestBody);
$result = Translate ($host, $path, $key, $params, $content);
// Note: We convert result, which is JSON, to and from an object so we can pretty-print it.
// We want to avoid escaping any Unicode characters that result contains. See:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
$json = jsonp_decode($result, true)[0]["translations"];
$conn = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

foreach ($json as $language) {
    $query = 'UPDATE kronen_translations SET translated_text = ? WHERE language_code = ?';
    $parameters = [$language['text'], $language['to']];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    echo $language['to'] . '<br>';
    echo $language['text'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I don’t see how this should have ever worked - you are trying to open a _local file system path_ here. If `api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?…` is supposed to be a _URL_, then it is of course missing the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit more investigation and eventually opened up a ticket with Microsoft Cognitive Services.  The script as it is / was was working fine a few months ago, and I was actually translating a couple of paragraphs into about 40 different languages (almost all that they support) using a bundled call single call and I would get a response back having all of the translations.  This was working fine before.

However, there is a character limits for API requests for the Translation Services:

See:  [Request limits for Translator Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/request-limits)

**"Each translate request is limited to 5,000 characters, across all the target languages you are translating to. For example, sending a translate request of 1,500 characters to translate to 3 different languages results in a request size of 1,500x3 = 4,500 characters, which satisfies the request limit. You're charged per character, not by the number of requests. It's recommended to send shorter requests."**

With 40 different languages and a couple of paragraphs having a few hundred characters I was over the limit.  After trading e-mails with MS support it turns out that the API request limit was not being enforced for part of last year and recently due to a bug on their end, and they fixed it recently apparently.

Just for reference, the old code was something like the following, with the query string having about 40 or so &to=lang& . . . .

```
$languages = $data['languagearray'];
$params = '&from=' . $data["from"] ;
foreach ($languages as $language) {
$params .= "&to=" . $language;
}
$params .= "&textType=html";
$text = $data["text"];

if (!function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
  function com_create_guid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
  }
}
function Translate ($host, $path, $key, $params, $content) {

    $headers = "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
        "Content-length: " . strlen($content) . "\r\n" .
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n" .
        "X-ClientTraceId: " . com_create_guid() . "\r\n";
    // NOTE: Use the key 'http' even if you are making an HTTPS request. See:
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
    $options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'header' => $headers,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $content
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create ($options);
    $result = file_get_contents ($host . $path . $params, false, $context);
    echo $result;
    return $result;
}
$requestBody = array (
    array (
        'Text' => $text,
    ),
);

function jsonp_decode($jsonp, $assoc = false) { // PHP 5.3 adds depth as third parameter to json_decode
    if($jsonp[0] !== '[' && $jsonp[0] !== '{') { // we have JSONP
       $jsonp = substr($jsonp, strpos($jsonp, '('));
    }
    return json_decode(trim($jsonp,'();'), $assoc);
}

$content = json_encode($requestBody);
$result = Translate ($host, $path, $key, $params, $content);
// Note: We convert result, which is JSON, to and from an object so we can pretty-print it.
// We want to avoid escaping any Unicode characters that result contains. See:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
$json = jsonp_decode($result, true)[0]["translations"];
$conn = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

foreach ($json as $language) {
    $query = 'UPDATE kronen_translations SET translated_text = ? WHERE language_code = ?';
    $parameters = [$language['text'], $language['to']];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    echo $language['to'] . '<br>';
    echo $language['text'] . '<br>';
}
```

You are allowed to make bundled calls like that, and then decode the results that you get back.

The solution was to make a series of calls (one at a time in this case), one for each language and then process the results in series.  The new code is something like this.  There might be a better way, but at least this way I can process reasonably sized chunks of text.  It just takes a bit of time to run the script for 40 or so languages, although still only my 30 seconds, depending upon the size of the text.

```
function Translate ($host, $path, $key, $params, $content) {

    $headers = "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
        "Content-length: " . strlen($content) . "\r\n" .
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n" .
        "X-ClientTraceId: " . com_create_guid() . "\r\n";
    // NOTE: Use the key 'http' even if you are making an HTTPS request. See:
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
    $options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'header' => $headers,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $content
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create ($options);
    $result = file_get_contents ($host . $path . $params, false, $context);
    echo $result;
    return $result;
}



function jsonp_decode($jsonp, $assoc = false) { // PHP 5.3 adds depth as third parameter to json_decode
    if($jsonp[0] !== '[' && $jsonp[0] !== '{') { // we have JSONP
       $jsonp = substr($jsonp, strpos($jsonp, '('));
    }
    return json_decode(trim($jsonp,'();'), $assoc);
}

$key = 'xxxxx';
$host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
$path = "/translate?api-version=3.0";
$languages = $data['languagearray'];
// print_r($languages);
$conn = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
$text = $data["text"];
foreach ($languages as $language) {
$params = '&from=' . $data["from"] ;
$params .= "&to=" . $language;
$params .= "&textType=html";
$text = $data["text"];

$requestBody = array (
    array (
        'Text' => $text,
    ),
);
$content = json_encode($requestBody);
$result = Translate ($host, $path, $key, $params, $content);
$json = jsonp_decode($result, true)[0]["translations"];

foreach ($json as $language) {
    $query = 'UPDATE kronen_translations SET translated_text = ? WHERE language_code = ?';
    $parameters = [$language['text'], $language['to']];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    echo $language['to'] . '<br>';
    echo $language['text'] . '<br>';
}
```